# withRouter alternative in react-router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Trying to import withRouter from react-router-dom

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

However I keep getting an error saying `Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router'.`

withRouter used to import fine in react-router v5, before I upgraded to v6. Not sure what the issue is now.